# Scaffold DB and Controller DBFirst Results in ModelState.IsValid = false

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core

**The Setup**

I have a database with two tables: `[Person]`, `[PersonType]`. So `[Person].PersonTypeID` has a foreign key relationship with `[PersonType].ID`

I have created an ASP.Net Core MVC project (edit: using .Net 7) in Visual Studio 2022, and have run the following code:

```
Scaffold-DBContext -connection name=DefaultConnection Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer -OutputDir Models -f
```

This generates the following classes:

```
public partial class Person
{
    [Key]
    [Column("ID")]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [Column("name")]
    [StringLength(100)]
    [Unicode(false)]
    public string Name { get; set; } = null!;

    [Column("personTypeID")]
    public int PersonTypeId { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("PersonTypeId")]
    [InverseProperty("People")]
    public virtual PersonType PersonType { get; set; } = null!;

    [InverseProperty("Person")]
    public virtual ICollection<RecurringTransaction> RecurringTransactions { get; set; } = new List<RecurringTransaction>();

    [InverseProperty("Person")]
    public virtual ICollection<SingleEntryTransactionImportRule> SingleEntryTransactionImportRules { get; set; } = new List<SingleEntryTransactionImportRule>();

    [InverseProperty("Person")]
    public virtual ICollection<SingleEntryTransaction> SingleEntryTransactions { get; set; } = new List<SingleEntryTransaction>();
}

public partial class PersonType
{
    [Key]
    [Column("ID")]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [Column("name")]
    [StringLength(50)]
    [Unicode(false)]
    public string Name { get; set; } = null!;

    [InverseProperty("PersonType")]
    public virtual ICollection<Person> People { get; set; } = new List<Person>();
}
```

And the following in my context file:

```
public ContextClass(DbContextOptions<ContextClass> options)
    : base(options)
{
}

...

public virtual DbSet<Person> Persons { get; set; }

public virtual DbSet<PersonType> PersonTypes { get; set; }

public virtual DbSet<RecurringTransaction> RecurringTransactions { get; set; }

...

protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
    => optionsBuilder.UseSqlServer("name=DefaultConnection");

protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    modelBuilder.UseCollation("SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS");

    ...

    modelBuilder.Entity<Person>(entity =>
    {
        entity.HasOne(d => d.PersonType).WithMany(p => p.People)
            .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.ClientSetNull)
            .HasConstraintName("FK_Persons_PersonTypes");
    });

    modelBuilder.Entity<PersonType>(entity =>
    {
        entity.HasKey(e => e.Id).HasName("PK_EntityTypes");
    });

    modelBuilder.Entity<RecurringTransaction>(entity =>
    {
        entity.HasOne(d => d.CreditAccount).WithMany(p => p.RecurringTransactionCreditAccounts)
            .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.ClientSetNull)
            .HasConstraintName("FK_RecurringTransactions_CreditAccounts");

        entity.HasOne(d => d.DebitAccount).WithMany(p => p.RecurringTransactionDebitAccounts)
            .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.ClientSetNull)
            .HasConstraintName("FK_RecurringTransactions_DebitAccounts");

        entity.HasOne(d => d.Person).WithMany(p => p.RecurringTransactions)
            .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.ClientSetNull)
            .HasConstraintName("FK_RecurringTransactions_Persons");
    });

    ...

    OnModelCreatingPartial(modelBuilder);
```

I then right click on the controllers folder and click 'Add' > 'Controller' which generates:

*Controller:*

```
[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public async Task<IActionResult> Create([Bind("Id,Name,PersonTypeId")] Person person)
{
      ModelState.Remove("PersonType");
      if (ModelState.IsValid)
      {
            _context.Add(person);
            await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
            return RedirectToAction(nameof(Index));
      }
      ViewData["PersonTypeId"] = new SelectList(_context.PersonTypes, "Id", "Id", person.PersonTypeId);
      return View(person);
}
```

*View:*

```
@model BirchtreeAccountingCoreBuild.Models.Person

@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "Create";
}

<h1>Create</h1>

<h4>Person</h4>
<hr />
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-4">
        <form asp-action="Create">
            <div asp-validation-summary="ModelOnly" class="text-danger"></div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="Name" class="control-label"></label>
                <input asp-for="Name" class="form-control" />
                <span asp-validation-for="Name" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="PersonTypeId" class="control-label"></label>
                <select asp-for="PersonTypeId" class ="form-control" asp-items="ViewBag.PersonTypeId"></select>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <input type="submit" value="Create" class="btn btn-primary" />
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>
</div>

<div>
    <a asp-action="Index">Back to List</a>
</div>

@section Scripts {
    @{await Html.RenderPartialAsync("_ValidationScriptsPartial");}
}
```

**The Problem**

When I run this code (aka when I go to localhost:xxxx/People/Create and fill in name and persontypeid, then press submit), `Model.IsValid` is false because PersonType property is null (and therefore is not saving my new Person to the db).

**My frustration**

This is frustrating for two reasons:

(A) All it takes is an existing database and an Update from Database call and a Add Controller scaffold in Visual Studio 2019 using .NET Framework 4.8. I am curious what has changed, that makes a quick database first CRUD website harder to do now?

(B) If I remove `name` or `persontypeid` from the Bind statement in the Create action, it no longer tries to validate them. So if PersonType is not in the bind statement, why is it trying to validate it?

(C) It must only have this issue with One to One, as other properties like RecurringTransactions are allowed to be null and they are ICollections.

(D) FluentAPI shows the Foreign Key relationship, so it should know its not supposed to have a value for that, since it is assumed by providing a personTypeID.

Below is what Visual Studio 2019 .NET Framework 4.8 generates when using Update from Database:

```
public partial class Person
{
    [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2214:DoNotCallOverridableMethodsInConstructors")]
    public Person()
    {
        this.SingleEntryTransaction_ImportRules = new HashSet<SingleEntryTransaction_ImportRules>();
        this.SingleEntryTransactions = new HashSet<SingleEntryTransaction>();
        this.RecurringTransactions = new HashSet<RecurringTransaction>();
    }

    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string name { get; set; }
    public int personTypeID { get; set; }

    public virtual PersonType PersonType { get; set; }
    [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2227:CollectionPropertiesShouldBeReadOnly")]
    public virtual ICollection<SingleEntryTransaction_ImportRules> SingleEntryTransaction_ImportRules { get; set; }
    [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2227:CollectionPropertiesShouldBeReadOnly")]
    public virtual ICollection<SingleEntryTransaction> SingleEntryTransactions { get; set; }
    [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2227:CollectionPropertiesShouldBeReadOnly")]
    public virtual ICollection<RecurringTransaction> RecurringTransactions { get; set; }
}
```

**Possible Solutions?**

(1) Create a ViewModel like CreatePersonFormViewModel, that will only have name, persontypeid.

(2) Use ModelState.Remove("PersonType") right before the check for ModelState.IsValid to remove unnecessary.

(3) Make persontype a nullable field in the Person model using the question mark, and remove the =null! (but this will be overridden if I ever update from db again). I am confused why the auto generated =null! for this PersonType property doesn't do the same thing.

```
public virtual PersonType? PersonType { get; set; }
```

(4) Use [Bind Never] for virtual model items?

```
[BindNever]
public PersonType PersonType { get; set; } = null!;
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess the version of `Asp.Net Core` you are using is .Net 6 or higher. Prior to .NET 6, new projects do not include the Nullable element. Beginning with .NET 6, new projects include the `<Nullable>enable</Nullable>` element in the project file.

The `PersonType` property is non-nullable(Equivalent to hermit adding a `[Required]` property) by default, So if you don't bind any value to this property, `ModelState.IsValid` will return false.

If you don't want this, In addition to the method you mentioned above, You can also disable this by deleting the below line from the `.csproj` file or setting it as disable. By default(.Net 6) value is enable.

```
<Nullable>enable</Nullable>
```

Comment: You are correct, as I am using .Net 7. So for a project where I have a full database already set up, and just want a quick 30 minute CRUD application, I can run the Scaffold-DBContext command, and scaffold the Controllers via right click > Add > Controller for each model needing CRUD functionality, comment out / delete <Nullable>enable</Nullable>, and it will be ready to go? It seems to be working for me. The only problems this introduces are ones I would have with .Net Framework 4.8 and the Update from Database UI option I was using before?

Comment: Of course you can let VS to generate CRUD controller for target model. You can refer to this [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/data/ef-mvc/crud?view=aspnetcore-7.0).